# pathlib return non-windows path with double slash

Tags: python-3.x

In Windows, when using pathlib, is there a way to output the path with a double back slash?

```
from pathlib import Path

working_directory = Path(r'C:\Downloads')
print(working_directory)
```

output is C:\Downloads\temp

How do I make the output a double back slash, such as: C:\\Downloads\\temp

Comment: Any particular reason you want to do that? Your path object is correct and usable as is.

Comment: I need to output to a csv, as the interfacing mailmerge file requires a file path with a double slash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `%r`:

```
from pathlib import Path

working_directory = Path(r'C:\Downloads')
print('%r'%str(working_directory))
```